# php + jquery + mysql + form action

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms

i am creating a form using php and jquery  to insert data to the database without refreshing the page but the problem is that the page refresh and direct me to the php page anyone can help me

## index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>feedback page</title>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel ="stylesheet" href = "css/default.css" />

<script type = "text/javascript">

$(function(){

   $('#submit').click(function(){
     $('#container').append('<img src = "img/loading.gif" alt="Currently loading" id = "loading" />');

         var name = $('#name').val();
         var email = $('#email').val();
         var comments = $('#comments').val();

           console.log(name, email, comments);
        return false;

   });


});

</script>




</head>

<body>
   <form action = "submit_to_db.php" method = "post">
   <div id = "container">
      <label for = "name">Name</label>
      <input type = "text" name = "name" id = "name" />

      <label for = "email">Email address</label>
      <input type = "text" name = "email" id = "email" />

      <label for = "comments">Comments</label>
      <textarea rows = "5"cols = "35" name = "comments" id = "comments"></textarea>
      <br />

      <input type = "submit" name = "submit" id = "name" value = "send feedBack" />
    </div>
   </form>



   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

## submit_to_db.php

```
<?php
  $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'my_db');
  $query = "INSERT into comments(name, email, comments) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";

  $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
  if($stmt->prepare($query)){

     $stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['comments']);
     $stmt->execute();

  }

  if($stmt){

  echo "thank you .we will be in touch soon";
  }
  else{
   echo "there was an error. try again later.";
   }  


?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" id = "name" value = "send feedBack" />
```

By

```
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" id = "submit" value = "send feedBack" />
```

Notice : **id**

Also you should trigger event on `(form).submit();` instead of `('submit').click();`

Comment: another solution would be to change the button from a submit to just button and post the form contents as a full blown ajax call to your back end pages then you can also remove the form tags as they're no longer needed :)

Comment: @AshwiniAgarwal I am not sure when he will login again... http://cdn2.planetminecraft.com/files/resource_media/screenshot/1243/sad-i-know-that-feel-bro_3969556_lrg.jpg